# SQL statement not deleting in PHP

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

```
echo $_POST['IDnum'];
$result = pg_prepare($conn, "city_delete",
    "DELETE FROM lab5.city WHERE lab5.city.id = $1");
$result = pg_execute($conn, "city_delete", array($_POST['IDnum']));
```

This displays the correct ID number for the row to be deleted and will delete it inside PSQL, but will not delete when implemented inside the PHP? Any ideas?

Comment: Um...care to actually show us the code?

Comment: Did you try in from the mysql command line? O r a tool like phpmyadmin? What error do you get? did you verify your query is correct?

Comment: No idea without seeing the code.

Comment: Sorry, code should be there now. I ran it inside the command line and it removed the right row when I hardcoded in the ID, but when I use post it won't delete it even though the post variable is the same number

Comment: Why is array() included in the final statement?

Comment: Did you try echoing pg_last_error()?
@JoeSpurling It's a prepeared statement, that's how you pass variables. It seems valid.

Comment: If you can actually get multiple ID's in IDNum you should use WHERE lab5.city.id IN ($1)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$result = pg_prepare($conn, "city_delete",
'DELETE FROM lab5.city WHERE lab5.city.id = $1');
```

The double quotes you used make the $1 a PHP variable instead of a string.

See the example for pg_prepare here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-prepare.php

Comment: pg_prepare() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given. This is the error when I ran with single quotes.

Comment: The first parameter is $conn, which would indicate a missing database connection (the resource mentioned)..check this for more info: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-connect.php

Comment: In case anyone reads this answer in the future: variable names in PHP must begin with [a-zA-Z_] (as well as the bytes 0x7f through 0xff, though irrelevant here). Double quotes will not cause variable interpolation in this case.