# SQL not deleting in php

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, sql-delete

***EDIT:  This IS resolved.  It was a simple case of querying the wrong schema name.  The rest of the code works (even if it is not great coding practice).***

This same question was asked here:

[SQL statement not deleting in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15231343/sql-statement-not-deleting-in-php)

I don't see a solid resolution on that thread though.  Basically my issue is that it says the delete was successful, but nothing was deleted.  I'm pretty sure it has to do with the $1 in the delete statements, but I don't know what else to try.  Could someone explain to me why this doesn't work?  Here is my code:

```
$mySearch = $_POST['row'];

if($_POST['tbl'] == "country"){
    $query = 'DELETE FROM lab2.country WHERE country.country_code = $1';
}
elseif($_POST['tbl'] == "city"){
    $query = 'DELETE FROM lab2.city WHERE city.id = $1';
 }
elseif($_POST['tbl'] == "language"){
    $query = 'DELETE FROM lab2.country_language WHERE country_language.country_code = $1';
}

$stmt = pg_prepare($conn, $mySearch, $query); //prepare statement
$result = pg_execute($conn, $mySearch, array($mySearch)); //execute

if(!$result){ //error if no value in $result
    die("Unable to execute: " . pg_last_error($conn));
} else{
       //results are good so output them to HTML
    echo "Delete was successful <br />";
    echo "Return to <a href=\"" . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] . "\">search page</a>";
}
pg_free_result($result);
    pg_close($conn);
return;
```

Comment: `E_DOESNT_WORK` is not a known PHP error code. What error do you actually get?

Comment: @EmilioGort: [Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-prepare.php):`If any parameters are used, they are referred to in the query as $1, $2, etc.`

Comment: You can try to watch the value of $query and manually run that query in your sql client.

Comment: @tereško, I did not receive an error.  The program runs fine.  It just does not delete what I want it to.

Comment: I meant to add more to that previous comment.  I printed $mySearch, and it does have the right value.  I tried changing the second parameter to $stmt, and I get error "Unable to execute: "

Comment: according to the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-execute.php) in the `pg_prepare`, you have to put as second parameter the The name to give the prepared statement. Must be unique per-connection. If "" is specified, then an unnamed statement is created, overwriting any previously defined unnamed statement. and in the `pg_execute ` the second parameter is the name pf the prepare statement

Comment: I didn't surround the $stmt parameter in double quotes the first time I tried.  putting it in double quotes gave me this error: Unable to execute: ERROR: prepared statement "Resource id #3" does not exist

Comment: Thank you for your responses.  I need to get some sleep, but i will check the feed in the morning.

Comment: Just to check, do you have a schema called `lab2` or do you expect this to be the name of your database?

Comment: Wow, Bruno you got it!  I have a schema, but it is called lab5, not lab2.  That is why you shouldn't stay up all night coding!  It works fine after I changed it to the correct schema name.  (I'm not sure if there is a way to up-vote comments.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems a bit odd to use `$mySearch` both as the actual parameter and as the name of the prepared statement, especially since you're preparing 3 different statements that are not actually a function of that variable (`$_POST['row']`) but depend on `$_POST['tbl']` instead.

Since you're redefining these statements every time, with a new name for the each new arguments, you're not actually gaining anything from re-use. This is likely to cause problems if you're searching with new arguments (since [you can't re-use the same name in the same session, unless it's the empty string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-prepare.php)). You might as well use `pg_query_params` instead.

If you really want to use prepared statements, give them 3 fixed different names (one for each of your 3 queries): it's `pg_execute` that will take care of using different parameters for these same queries the following time.

One of the problems you may run into with these prepared statements, depending on the code around this, is if you're trying to redefine them again with the same name in the same session. I can't find a binding for `libpq`'s `PQdescribePrepared` in PHP, but you could use the [`pg_prepared_statements` view](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/view-pg-prepared-statements.html) to see if there already is a prepared statement against the names you choose in the current session, before using `pg_prepare`.

The result of `pg_prepare` should also be a result that you should check for errors (it's not really a statement, as the `$stmt` variable name you've used seems to suggest).

---

*EDIT:*

As I said in a comment (which seems to lead to the suitable solution), it's also worth checking that `lab2` is the right schema name. I was just a bit surprised by this because it's unusual to use schema if you're new to PostgreSQL (most people would just use `public` to start with), but I guess this may come from existing data provided by someone else. (Using "`database_name.table_name`" would also have been an easy mistake to make if you'd come from a MySQL background.)

Comment: I agree.  I thought using $mySearch for both was strange, but it worked for me earlier.  Now that I have it working, I will play around with the prepare statement and see if I can find a better way of coding it.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-prepare.php) in the `pg_prepare`, you have to put as second parameter the name to give the prepared statement. Must be unique per-connection. If "" is specified, then an unnamed statement is created, overwriting any previously defined unnamed statement. and in the `pg_execute` the second parameter is the name of the prepare statement.

This:

```
$stmt = pg_prepare($conn, $mySearch, $query); //prepare statement
$result = pg_execute($conn, $mySearch, array($mySearch)); //execute
```

Should be:

```
$result = pg_prepare($conn, "my_query", $query); //prepare statement
$result = pg_execute($conn, "my_query", array($mySearch)); //execute
```

[pg_execute](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-execute.php)

Comment: This does not work.  It runs through okay like the original code, but it does not delete anything.  Thank you for the response though.

Comment: I think you have to do some basic debug, test what `if` is executing, and see if the `$mySearch` match with your criteria to delete the record, and try to see in the postgreSQL's log, what query are you getting when you execute the php

Comment: try to read the comments in http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-prepare.php#usernotes there might be a solution

Comment: @Bill try the comments above

Comment: I appreciate the help.  Unfortunately I have looked at the documentation and still haven't figured it out.  I am still pretty new to all of html, php, and postgresql, so there may be something else I am overlooking.

Comment: the problem was just that I typed in the wrong schema name.  It was lab5, not lab2.  I told Bruno the same thing, but now that I have it working I will play with the prepare statement to see if I can find a better way of coding it.  Thanks for your help.